Replacing a fibration with a "cellular" fibration

The question I have is to my mind a natural question in the theme of CW-replacement. Given a homotopy fiber sequence $F\to E\to B$ of spaces with the homotopy type of CW-complexes can I find a homotopy fiber sequence $F'\to E'\to B'$ equivalent (as homotopy fiber sequences) such that each $F',E', B'$ is a CW complex and the maps are all cellular? 
For me this arose while studying crossed modules and their relation to homotopy two types, my end goal is to get some relation between the crossed modules associated to the spaces in a homotopy fiber sequence. 
My intution so far is that changing the base space and the map to the base space is the easiest part, and the rest is a bit murkier. In particular, with all of my attempted construction, I am having trouble, after using some CW replacement, to get a map to/from my original fiber sequence to the new "cellular" fiber sequence. 
Any help, solution or ressource is greatly appreciated, thank you very much.

What do you mean by "homotopy fibration"?

A sequence $F\to E\to B$ where $\Omega B$ acts on $F$, homotopy equivalent to a sequence $\tilde{F}\to\tilde{E}\to\tilde{B}$ where $\tilde{F}$ is the homotopy fiber of the map $\tilde{E}\to\tilde{B}$. And the notion of "homotopy equivalent" for sequences is pointwise + compatible with action of the base space on the fiber. Though thanks to your remark I realize the correct terminology is "homotopy fiber sequence", thanks!

Shouldn't "replace $E \to B$ with a CW-approximation $E' \to B'$, then take its homotopy fibre $F' \to E'$ and replace it, too, with a CW-approximation $F'' \to E'$" then work on the nose? All the approximation maps are equivalences since you assumed $F, E, B$ to have the homotopy type of a CW-complex, and they by design assemble into an equivalence of homotopy fibre sequences.

The point which isn't clear to me in your construction, is when replacing $F'$ with $F''$, how do we know $F''\to E'\to B'$ is a homotopy fiber sequence? (I.e $F''$ is the homotopy pull back of $*\to B'\leftarrow E') But I might be missing some argument.

Ah, I guess the question is whether $F'$ has the homotopy type of a CW-complex. I believe this should be true based on a concrete description of the homotopy fibre as a subspace of $E' \times (B')^I$ and techniques from Milnor's paper on the homotopy types of CW-complexes, but don't take my word for it. If I find the time I'll try and work it out.
